# New-ADGroup name has bad syntax

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am getting a `bad syntax` error when trying to create a `New-ADGroup`. It doesn't matter where I put the quotes, how I change, I can add it manually but with this script.

Here is some of the script and output:

```
$domain="xyz"
$tldn="net"
$ouP2="OU=ABC,DC=$domain,DC=$tldn"

# Asks for a project number and a project name then appends a fixed group name with this string
[int]$projectNumber=try { Read-Host -Prompt "Enter project number" } catch { Write-Host "Not a numeric value. Please try again."; exit }
$projectNumberString=[string]$projectNumber

# Script creates Organization Units with `New-ADOrganizationalUnit` and makes directories with `New-Item` just fine and uses $fullProjectName just fine
# However, when I use that name to create the group, it gives me a bad syntax error
New-ADGroup -Name $domain\$group -SamAccountName $domain\$group -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -DisplayName $domain\$group -Path $ouP2 -Description "test share"

New-ADGroup : The object name has bad syntax
At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Fiverr\Tas1.ps1:101 char:1
+ New-ADGroup -Name $domain\$group -SamAccountName $domain\$group -GroupCategory S ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=WOLF\\Elite_...ssOU,DC=,DC=net:String) [New-ADGrou 
   p], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8335,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Comm 
   ands.NewADGroup
```

I added a group successfully when I ran the command manually:

`$groupname="dodobird815pm"; New-ADGroup -Name $groupname -SamAccountName $groupname -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -DisplayName $groupname -Path "OU=ABC,DC=XYZ,DC=net" -Description "test group"`

This group appeared in ADUC under the specified.

I echoed the `$domain\$group` with `Write-Host $domain\$group` and the output looked good: `XYZ\ABC_802`; so, I am not sure why there is bad syntax. I have been working on this for hours now, and I am ready to throw this script in the fire. Please help, thank you!

**EDIT**

Changed the group variable:

```
$group="ABC_"+[string]${projectNumber}
$groupdomain=$domain+"\"+$group
```

The added the `$groupdomain` variable to `New-ADGroup` and the results are the same.

`New-ADGroup -Name $groupdomain -SamAccountName $groupdomain -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -DisplayName $groupdomain -Path $ouP2 -Description "Members of this group have read and write access to this share"`

Added a `Write-Host $domaingroup` and the output was the same as before, which is `ZYX\ABC_1041`.

Your help is appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**

I tried added just a `"ABC_1234"` as a test to the `-Name` in `New-ADGroup` but received the same error. I also took the `$domain` out and just used `$group` for the `Name,SAMAccountId,DisplayName` but that did not change the error.

According to technet and ss64, the `Name,SAMaccountId,DisplayName` is supposed to accept a string. As a far as I know, this is a string.

Comment: I don't see you initialize the `$group`. Therefore your script tries to `New-ADGroup $null` and gets an error.

Comment: Try `New-ADGroup -Name $group -SamAccountName $group -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -DisplayName $group -Path $ouP2 -Description "test share"`

Comment: @Vesper and Micky Balladelli The problem wound up being that because I used `+` to combine strings earlier in the script, somehow the `""` were stripped, and so adding `"$group"` instead of `$group` wound up working. Spending hours on something resolved by double-quotes is almost embarrassing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MickyBalladelli I have a much worse problem at [this SOF post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44225229/powershell-set-acl-new-object-cannot-find-an-overload-for-filesystemaccessrul) if you don't mind helping me. Thanks.