# PowerShell ACL Not Applying

Tags: powershell, acl

I have an issue with setting an ACL to a folder using PowerShell. It seems I was able to get through my code without any errors, but the folder still does not appear in the Security properties of the folder. The other articles I looked at seemed to have answers, but then comments, if any, that it didn't work, and after trying what the answers suggested, it did not result in the group appearing in the System properties of the folder.

My script so far is as follows:

$domain="DOMAIN"
    $tldn="net"

```
$pathArr=@()
$pathArr+=$path1=Read-Host -Prompt "Enter first path"
$pathArr+=$path2=Read-Host -Prompt "Enter second path"
[int]$projectNumber=try { Read-Host -Prompt "Enter project number" } catch { Write-Host "Not a numeric value. Please try again."; exit }
[string]$mainFolder=[string]${projectNumber}+"_"+(Read-Host -Prompt "Please give the main folder name")
$projectNumberString=[string]$projectNumber
$projectName=Read-Host -Prompt "Please give the project name"
$fullProjectName="${projectNumberString}_${projectName}"
$pathArr+=$path3="$path1\$mainFolder"
$pathArr+=$path4="$path2\$mainFolder"
$pathArr+=$path5="$path3\$fullProjectName"
$pathArr+=$path6="$path4\$fullProjectName"

# Region: Create organizational units in Active Directory
# Names
$ouN1="XYZOU"
$ouN2="ABCOU"

# Paths
$ouP0="DC=$domain,DC=$tldn"
$ouP1="OU=$ouN1,$ouP0"
$ouP2="OU=$ouN2,$ouP1"

Write-Host "Checking for required origanization units..."
try
{
    New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name $ouN1 -Path $ouP1
    New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name $ouN2 -Path $ouP2

}
catch
{
    Out-Null
}
```

**EDIT**

As per Mickey's comment, I added this code to test the path of `$path6`'

```
if ( Test-Path -Path "$path6" )
{
    Write-Host "$path6"
    Write-Host "Path exists."
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Path does not exist."
}
```

The result was that the path wrote to the host and said `Path exists.`. 
    Write-Host "Creating AD Group..."
    [string]$group="BEST_${projectNumberString}"
    $groupdomain="$domain\$group"

```
$ADGroupParams= @{
    'Name' = "$group" 
    'SamAccountName' = "$group" 
    'GroupCategory' = "Security"
    'GroupScope' = "Global"
    'DisplayName' = "$group"
    'Path' = "OU=MyBusinessOU,DC=$domain,DC=$tldn"
    'Description' = "Test share"
}
$secgroup=New-ADGroup @ADGroupParams

# Region: Set permissions
Write-Host "Setting permissions..."

# get permissions
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $path6

# add a new permission
$InheritanceFlags=[System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]”ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit”
$FileSystemAccessRights=[System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Traverse","Executefile","ListDirectory","ReadData", "ReadAttributes", "ReadExtendedAttributes","CreateFiles","WriteData", 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit', "CreateDirectories","AppendData", "WriteAttributes", "WriteExtendedAttributes", "DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles", "ReadPermissions"
$InheritanceFlags=[System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]”ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit”
$PropagationFlags=[System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]”None”
$AccessControl=[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]”Allow”
$permission = "$groupdomain", "$InheritanceFlags", "$PropagationFlags", "$AccessControl"
$rule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permission
$acl.SetAccessRule($rule)

# set new permissions
$acl | Set-Acl -Path $path6
```

I tried `Set-Acl -ACLObject:$acl -Path:$path6` and that didn't work either.

Again, I am not getting any errors at all.

I am running PowerShell 4.0 in PowerShell ISE on Windows Server 2012 R2. I am logged in as Administrator.

If you have any ideas, I am open to them. To be clear, my goal is to add the `$groupdomain` to a folder called `path6`, and have the ACLs outlined here applied to that group.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `$path6` ? Does it exist?

Comment: Wow so File Explorer does not display the group in Folder Properties -> Security. However, when I added a `Get-ACL` to the script for `$path6`, it was listed. Does that mean that once the script ends, the ACL also deletes?

Comment: I regress. This is actually something much more ridiculous. The script's `$path6` is not what I had in mind, so I was looking in the wrong place. Amazing. It is a sub-folder under where I was looking with the same name. Need to fix that.

Comment: Do you still have an issue in adding the ACL? You could open a powershell window and do `Get-Acl <value of $path6>` to see if there is an ACL?

Comment: I don't anymore. Thank you @MickyBalladelli for your help! It was just calling the wrong directory variable. Your suggestions resolved it. Feel free to answer the question and I'll mark iy so.